# Chromebug - debug firefox extension with "components" folder

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, chromebug

I want to debug some Firefox extensions. I tried with two debugging tools - Chromebug and JavaScript Debugger (Venkman).

One of the extensions has the following structure:

- components folder
- content folder
- platform folder
- resource folder
  chrome.manifest
  install.rdf

Unfortunately I can't change the extension's structure and Chromebug doesn't catch JavaScript files in "components" folder, so I can't debug them.

For my bad luck JavaScript Debugger doesn't work as I expected and it stops on files, which don't have any breakpoints, so most of the time it's impossible to debug my files.

Am I doing something wrong or there is no way debug Firefox extensions without any problems?

Comment: Use an XUL tool, such as [XUL Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Explorer).